# Why do these angle values imply collinearity?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I have another question about [this](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/Morley/Bollobas.shtml) proof of Morley's theorem. Towards they end it says $\angle RR_{2}R_{1}=\gamma^{+}\implies R_{1}$ is on segment $AR_{2}$. I dont understand why this is true.

Figure for refernce:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By construction (reflecting $Q$ over $\overline{AR}$), we have that $|\angle RR_2A| = \gamma^+$.

By some other angle chasing, it turns out that $|\angle RR_2R_1| = \gamma^+$ as well.

So, *both* $\overrightarrow{R_2A}$ *and* $\overrightarrow{R_2R_1}$ make an angle of $\gamma^+$ with $\overrightarrow{R_2R}$.

*However*, only one ray on a given side of $\overrightarrow{R_2R}$ can form an angle of a particular size with it, so $\overrightarrow{R_2A}$ and $\overrightarrow{R_2R_1}$ must be the same ray. Consequently, points $A$, $R_1$, and $R_2$ must be collinear.